# What does % mean in code next to variable?

Tags: c++, c

Let's say x=29 and y=13. What does this line of code actually do:

```
x%=y-3;
```

I just don't really know what does this mean?

Comment: Its the modulus operator: [https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html)

Comment: `x %= y - 3` is the same thing as `x = x % (y - 3)`. For the rest see the duplicate

Comment: The `%` is not a variable postfix; it is a prefix to `=`. It is a short way to do `x = x % (y - 3);`. `%` means modulo.

Comment: Spaces around the operators makes code much more readable.

Comment: This is worth a re-open. OP is asking about `%=`, which has different properties to plain old `%`. Also prefer the term *remainder operator*?

Comment: how it's different property?

Comment: It has a different precedence for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modulo operator gives you remainder from division.

`a % b` is the remainder of division a by b

`x %= y - 3` is equal to `x = x % (y - 3)` and gives you remainder from division x by (y - 3) expression.

Comment: OP should do their homework but as you already posted an answer it would be good IMO to  describe the difference between modulus and the remainder when negative arguments are used. For example, `10 % -3` would give 1 in C but would give -2 in Python.